# Where have all my Nuget transitive dependencies gone?

Tags: nuget, owin

## Problem Statement

I'm upgrading a local environment from Sitecore `10.3` to `10.3.1`.  The platform is easy enough to upgrade using Docker with an update to my IMAGE TAG version: `10.3-ltsc2019` to `10.3.1-ltsc2019`.  Upgrading my Visual Studio solution should also be straightforward with Centralized Package Management using the `Packages.props` file.

### Before

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformVersion>10.3.0</PlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Kernel" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.Platform" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.SitecoreHeadlessServicesServer" Version="21.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.LayoutService" Version="9.0.310" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### After

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformVersion>10.3.1</PlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Kernel" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.Platform" Version="$(PlatformVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.Assemblies.SitecoreHeadlessServicesServer" Version="21.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Update="Sitecore.LayoutService" Version="9.0.310" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, when I build my solution, I get several build errors for Nuget dependencies that were previously included in the `10.3.0` version.

Here's a comparison of the dependency tree for the `Sitecore.Kernel` nuget package:

[image: Sitecore.Kernel Dependency Tree]

Are developers expected to manually add any package dependencies for Sitecore 10.3.1 and above?

What up with that?

Comment: Agreed, that is a very annoying change of approach, it will likely break the builds on many solutions that use PackageReference, not sure I see the point of it, other than making the dependency tree look neater.

Comment: I think they did it to minimize vulnerable software packages showing up in code scanning tools like Checkmarx, but I haven’t found anything in the change log that explains how the DevEx is expected to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading I ran into build issues because of this.

After installing the necessary NuGet packages you're now missing because of the fact that they aren't dependencies anymore, you will get errors around having version numbers in your csproj files, so you will need to remove the version numbers. Then you'll need to add the package references to Packages.Props.

In my case, I was missing `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstracts`. I just installed the NuGet packages and altered the csproj files and Packages.Props.

csproj:
[image]

Packages.props:
[image]

Comment: Please add the code snippets with your answer along with the image for SEO purposes.

Comment: I agree with Andy.  Unless Sitecore has another suggestion, it seems that developers are responsible for identifying the required, version-specific transitive dependencies of the Sitecore nuget packages for version 10.3.1+